# How to run Android player in Window mode?

Tags: android, adb

I have Android Machine setup. I want to run the players in window mode as of now they run in full screen mode. so how do I run the Android video player in Window mode ?

Comment: Can you give in more detail ? or share some code if possible ?

Comment: I have android machine setup and when I run video player like MXplayer or Mobo player they play video in full screen mode. I want to run video in window mode.